# Netlogo, Checking if two agents are connected to the same agent

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem I wish to solve. Lets say there are two type of agents (rabbits and hunters). I want the hunters to find the closest rabbit to them. But if two hunters were to find the same rabbit  (i.e the closest rabbit to hunter 103 and hunter 105 is rabbit 99). I want one of the hunters to find the next closest rabbit. So each hunters need to check which rabbits the other hunters are connected to and if any hunter is connected to same rabbit, find the next closest rabbit. Any ideas how to solve this. Thanks

```
breed [hunters hunter]
breed [rabbits rabbit]

hunters-own [rab-in-sight]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-hunters 20
  create-rabbits 100

  ask hunters [
  set color red
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask rabbits [
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

end

to connect
  ask hunters [
    set rab-in-sight min-one-of rabbits in-radius 5 [distance myself]
  ]

end
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use either a variable that indicates whether a rabbit has been targeted, or use `links` to accomplish the same thing.

### Link approach

Check out this modified version of your `setup` that has hunters set their `rab-in-sight` to `nobody`:

```
breed [hunters hunter]
breed [rabbits rabbit]

hunters-own [rab-in-sight]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-hunters 20
  create-rabbits 100

  ask hunters [
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set rab-in-sight nobody
  ]
  ask rabbits [
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Then, use `if` or `ifelse` statements to control hunter behavior based on whether it is currently hunting a rabbit:

```
to go
  ask hunters [ 
    connect
  ]
  tick
end

to connect
  ; If a hunter is not already targetting a rabbit
  ifelse rab-in-sight = nobody [
    fd 1

    ; Choose a target rabbit that does not already have a link with other hunters
    set rab-in-sight min-one-of ( rabbits in-radius 5 with [ 
      not any? my-links ] ) [distance myself]

    ; If that rabbit exists, create a link with it so no other hunters will 
    ; target the same rabbit
    if rab-in-sight != nobody [
      create-link-with rab-in-sight
    ]
  ] [
    ; If you're targetting a rabbit, hunt it
    face rab-in-sight
    ifelse distance rab-in-sight > 1 [
      fd 1
    ] [
      move-to rab-in-sight
      ask rab-in-sight [
        die
      ] 
      set rab-in-sight nobody
    ]
  ]
end
```

### Variable approach

The flag or semaphore variable approach is similar- a slightly modified `setup` now sets `rab-in-sight` to `nobody` and gives `rabbits` a `targeted?` boolean variable that is set to `false`:

```
breed [hunters hunter]
breed [rabbits rabbit]

hunters-own [rab-in-sight]
rabbits-own [ targeted? ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-hunters 20
  create-rabbits 100

  ask hunters [
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set rab-in-sight nobody
  ]
  ask rabbits [
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set targeted? false
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Now, when a hunter targets a rabbit it has that rabbit change its `targeted?` variable to `true` so that other hunters "know" not to target it as well:

```
to go
  ask hunters [ 
    connect
  ]
  tick
end

to connect
  ; If a hunter is not already targetting a rabbit
  ifelse rab-in-sight = nobody [
    fd 1

    ; Choose a target rabbit that is not currently being targeted
    set rab-in-sight min-one-of ( rabbits in-radius 5 with [ 
      not targeted? ] ) [distance myself]

    ; If that rabbit exists, have it set targetted? to true so 
    ; no other hunters will target the same rabbit
    if rab-in-sight != nobody [
      ask rab-in-sight [
        set targeted? true
      ]
    ]
  ] [
    ; If you're targetting a rabbit, hunt it
    face rab-in-sight
    ifelse distance rab-in-sight > 1 [
      fd 1
    ] [
      move-to rab-in-sight
      ask rab-in-sight [
        die
      ] 
      set rab-in-sight nobody
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I recommend creating a seperate agent-set for the rabbits, say `rabbits-not-hunted`. The hunter selects one of the rabbits close by in this set, while the selected rabbit is removed from this set. Therefore the next hunter cannot select this rabbit as a target anymore and selects the next "free" prey. Please check the code below:

```
breed [hunters hunter]
breed [rabbits rabbit]

hunters-own [rab-in-sight]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-hunters 20
  create-rabbits 100

  ask hunters [
  set color red
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask rabbits [
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

end

to connect
  ;; a seperate agentset of all rabbits which are not hunted yet. At first, all rabbits can be hunted, therefore it coincides with all rabbits
  let rabbits-not-hunted rabbits

  ask hunters [
    ;; the prospective prey is taken from the set of rabbits-not-hunted yet
    let prospective-prey turtle-set min-one-of rabbits-not-hunted in-radius 5 [distance myself] 

    set rab-in-sight prospective-prey

    ;; updates rabbits-not-hunted agentset by removeing the prey selected from the agentset
    set rabbits-not-hunted rabbits-not-hunted with [ not member? self prospective-prey ]
  ]

end
```

Please note, that the code can produce errors if there is just one rabbit within the radius of hunter while this rabbit is already a target of another hunter. Given the hunter-prey ratio in your code, this is unlikely to happen, nevertheless I wanted to give you a fair warning for this.